# "could not find stored procedure <procedure name>"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a simple procedure that will give me the table entries containing a similar keyword.

Procedure:

```
USE ResourceRequest
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE resource_lookup @ProjectName nvarchar(100)=null
AS
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].Resource_Request
WHERE [Project Name] LIKE @ProjectName + '%'
GO
```

I can execute the procedure but there appears to be something wrong with 
"[dbo].[resource_lookup]" because it could not be found? I'm currently logged into the test server and can see the procedure in the "Stored Procedures" folder? What is causing this problem?

```
    USE [ResourceRequest]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[resource_lookup]
        @ProjectName = N'mutually'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't specify an explicit schema in the `create` so it creates it in your default schema which looks like it isn't dbo.

Use

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.resource_lookup @ProjectName nvarchar(100)=null
AS
/* ... */
```

To ensure it is created as desired.

---

But it sounds like this is an intellisense warning rather than a runtime error.

So use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to [refresh the intellisense cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2008/09/11/refreshing-the-intellisense-cache.aspx) so it picks up your newly added object.

Or if that doesn't work (some SSMS addins hijack this combination) do it through the menu options `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache`

[image: Menu screenshot]

Comment: I keep getting the same error despite that change. I renamed the procedure but the red line keeps coming back. :(

Comment: @thatdude if you are talking about an intellisense error rather than a runtime error you just need to refresh the cache.

Comment: The redline will remain until you refresh the cache for IntelliSense (<CTRL>-<SHIFT>-R). If you're actually running it and getting that error then it's something else though.

Comment: wow, I feel pretty embarrassed I couldn't figure that out. The intellisense error is gone. Thank you all for the help.